# Mailchimp DMARC Failures 4% of the time

Tags: mailchimp, spf, dkim, dmarc

Here is my weekly Postmark DMARC Digest. I currently have an allow-all DMARC policy. My last 4 weekly digests have all looked pretty similar as far as DKIM and SPF failures.

[DMARC Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeWRE.jpg)

I know that Mailchimp can't be SPF-aligned because of the way they configure their service, but it can be DKIM aligned.

As you can see Mailchimp fails DKIM Alignment about 4% of the time. I thought it should be good 99.9% of the time.

Is this normal?

Should I enable a quarantine or reject DMARC policy and lose 4% of my contacts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for a Mailchimp support ticket rather than here.

Comment: Can you drill down into your reports? Usually, you can see a reason for failure and the used selector and domain in your DKIM signing. The issue could be related to a specific receiving party or intermittent DNS lookup failures on your end.

Comment: By the way, Server Fault may be a better place to post this question.

Comment: @Synchro Thank you all for your suggestions. I will open a ticket with MailChimp and see what they say.

Comment: @Reinto, thanks. Sadly the report is a free service from Postmark and offers no details beyond what was shown in my screenshot. I will first see what MailChimp says then I might upgrade the Postmark service so I can see the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Mailchimp support:

> This can really just boil down to the receiving server's e-mail
> settings -- stricter policies are going to filter out e-mails from
> major ESPs like Mailchimp and that can result in you seeing some
> unexpected results, like what we're seeing here.